# how to save jwt token in databse asp .net 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to Save jwt token in the database I share the code of the controller where token generation is done but I don't know how to save the token or that code will work or nor

---

### this is my controller where use jwt token

```
 public class LoginController: Controller
     {
         private readonly JwtAuthContext _context;
         private IConfiguration _config;


         public LoginController(IConfiguration config, JwtAuthContext
context)
         {
             _config = config;
             _context = context;
         }

         [Route("api/Register")]
         [HttpPost]
         public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Register register)
         {

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 _context.Add(register);
                 _context.SaveChanges();
             }
             Console.WriteLine(register);
             var ttt = _context.Registers.ToList();
             return Ok(new { result = ttt });

         }

         [HttpPost]
         public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Login Login)
         {
             var user = Authenticate(Login);

             if (user != null)
             {
                 var token = Generate(user);
                 _context.SaveChanges();
                 return Ok(token);
             }

             return NotFound("User not found");
         }

         private string Generate(Register user)
         {
             var securityKey = new
SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
             var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey,
SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

             var claims = new[]
             {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Email),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.FullName),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
             };

             var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
               _config["Jwt:Audience"],
               claims,
               expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
               signingCredentials: credentials);

             return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
         }
         private Register Authenticate(Login Login)
         {
             var currentUser = _context.Registers.FirstOrDefault(o =>
o.Email.ToLower() == Login.Email.ToLower() && o.Password == Login.Password);


             if (currentUser != null)
             {
                 return currentUser;
             }

             return null;
         }
```

this is my login model where I create a table of login

```
public class login{

public int LoginId{get;set;}
public string Email{get;set;}

public string Password{get;set;}

}
```

this is my register model where I can create a register model

```
public class Register{

public int Id{get;set;}

public string FullName{get;set;}

public string Email{get;set;}

public string Password{get;set;}

}
-------------
JwtAuthContext
--------------
 public class JwtAuthContext : DbContext
     {
         public JwtAuthContext(DbContextOptions<JwtAuthContext> options)
             : base(options)
         {
         }

         public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Register> Registers { get; set; }

         public DbSet<AuthenticationToken> authenticationTokens { get;
set; }
     }

This is my AuthenticationToken Model

public class AuthenticationToken
{
public string Token{get;set;}

}
```

Comment: why do want to save token in database ?

Comment: My teacher will give an assignment of jwt token and saved token in the database but when I submit the form token will not generate

Comment: how does your JwtAuthContext look like ?. you are not saving token anywhere so definitely it will not be stored in db.

Comment: on a side note, if this is an assignment you should figure out how do this instead of asking here

Comment: @CodingMytra i create a model of authenticationtoken there I define token

Comment: also without  using the database my token will not generate

Comment: but where is the code when you are adding to your jwtauthcontext. just add the code for jwtauthcontext and authenticationtoken model

Comment: yes my question is how I added to `JwtAuthContext`

Comment: add your current code of JwtAuthContext and will tell you how

Comment: yeah i update the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
         if (user != null)
         {
             var token = Generate(user);
             _context.authenticationTokens.Add(token); // just add this line
             _context.SaveChanges();
             return Ok(token);
         }
```

Comment: in this line `_context.authenticationTokens.Add(token);` token giving error cannot convert string to jwtauthentication1.models.authentication.Token

Comment: you need to create a object of  jwtauthentication1.models.authentication.Token and then assign token string to it.

Comment: i create object ee i update in question